# Detect unresolved symbols when linking my own static library due to forgotten source files

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I've had problems when building a large static library that sometimes I've forgotten to add certain source files to the project. Since this is a static library there are no linker warnings until the end user, who is using a public API, is using a method that is calling one of these missing symbols. Is there any way to make sure all the "library local" symbols are resolved at linking time?

Comment: That's what unit tests are for.

Comment: and make files. you're unlikely to leave an object file out of a library if it's in a make file

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @PeteBecker in the comments, this is about testing.

Create an executable that uses the static library and as long as it uses all the features you will catch missing objects very quickly, during link.

Make this executable test all the features and it doubles as your unit test facility as well.

Comment: And run these tests on a regular basis, like every night or even better, after every commit into the source repository.